# AWS EC2 ubuntu box authentication by using Azure AD

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, azure

I need your help to integrate user account on AWS EC2 ubuntu box by using Azure AD Credentials.
We have an azure account where we have created users which in used by email and other SSO services.
we already enable SSO to login into AWS by using Azure auth.
now, we would like to enable EC2 ubunt box login by using Azure user IDs. I tried the same but found this feature is available only in ubuntu23. but we needs to use ubuntu 22.04 only as It's LTS.

Can someone please guide/help me for where lookup or any how/to - suggestion.. will be much helpful.

Comment: Hmmm can you reconsider? You really should use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
Finally, i have found a better solution for this issue.
i have enabled ADDDS on azure and synced by using Azure connect in AWS EC2 AD.
and then i have enabled EC2 ubuntu boxes authentication by using AWS EC2 AD.
If anyone is looking for more details then please let me know. i will share step by step on this.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer would become more of an asset to Ask Ubuntu if you could share a step by step guide, as you have mentioned.